# CSS IE inputbox "padding-right" issue

Tags: html, css

I came across a problem and I tried searching on google and here too, however, could not get the right solution. Let me be brief...

I have a div name #email_input_box which contains `<input type="text" class="email_box" border="0" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin:0; border:0;" />`

The issue is in padding the text, it works fine in other browsers, however, it does not work in IE7.

Here's my .email_box class styling

```
.email_box{
    width:160px;
    height:26px;
    background:url(images/inputbox_email.png) no-repeat;
    line-height:26px;
    color:#969595;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;




}
```

and here's my div #email_input_box styling

```
#email_input_box{
    width:180px;
    height:26px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;


}
```

I need help with the padding-right issue in IE7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input doesn't have a **border** attribute, remove it.

```
<input type="text" class="email_box" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin:0; border:0;" />
```

this may solve the problem. however even if it doesn't, it should be removed.

Also the div containing the input have a less width than the input.

Comment: Mobayen Khiaba : Thanks for your response. I removed it however, the padding issue in IE remains.

Comment: i'll see if i can figure it out and then i will let you know.

Comment: please increase the width of the div and see what happens. its height is less than the input's width.

Comment: Mobayen Khiaba : Thanks again.. :)

Comment: is it solved? the problem is i have IE9, so i'm not albe to test it and make sure before i write it here ;)

Comment: Got it right!!! Actually, I deducted the width of the box as I have given an inline padding in both sides....I didnt knew IE7 does need the deduction of the width. Thanks for your time...:D